# How do you handle persistence with your Domain Models?

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design, persistence

Since domain models are supposed to be plain objects how does one handle persistence?
It's my understanding that all persistence must be made in the Application Layer but how do your Domain Models inform your Application Layer of any CRUD operations that need to be made to then pass them to a repository?

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Domain objects are passed to repositories which handles persistence concerns.

Comment: thanks plalx, that is how i'm doing it in my current project. when ever I have to made a decision on how to implement DDD... I always feel like i'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Well, do a search on "DDD tactical patterns" and being in doubt is what will make you progress ;)

Comment: DDD itself has nothing to do with persistence. Persistence is just the repository from the domain's point of view.

Answer (score 1):

The domain doesn't inform the Application layer of CRUD operations. It's unaware of how or when domain objects should be persisted. It's the application layer that decides when to conclude a given applicative transaction and flush changes to the persistent store.

Answer (score 0):

The responsabilty of the **application** is to orchestrate actions in the domain. The **domain** objects contains the logic and the business rules but it desn't know all the flux of the application. The number of steps required to fulfill an application needs stay in the application layer. The **repository** handles the persistence, but is the application that calls it.

Example:

```
Customer customer = customerRepository.GetById(2);
customer.Rename("Jhon Doe");
customerRepository.Save(customer);
```

Answer (score -1):

[Domain Services](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/21/services-in-domain-driven-design/) is the concept you're looking for.

Domain services are injected into a entity/domain object. The domain object calls the service via an interface.

EDIT: this example is C#, since it's my mother-tongue. If you're language has support for "[interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_(object-oriented_programming))", you can apply the concepts here.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Order myOrder = new Order(new OrderRepository());

        myOrder.Save();
    }
}

public interface IOrderRepository
{
    void Save(Order order);
}

public class OrderRepository : IOrderRepository
{
    public void Save(Order order)
    {
          // Persistence stuff here
    }
}

public class Order
{
    private IOrderRepository _orderRepository;
    public Order(IOrderRepository orderRepository)
    {
        _orderRepository = orderRepository;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _orderRepository.Save(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Letting entities know about persistence details is against DDD core principles. The application service is responsible for interacting with the repository and the entity should have no knowledge of it.

Comment: @plalx : it's perfectly fine for an entity to know about an application service, as long as the entity accesses the service via an interface. The Order entity has a "Save" method, because "saving the order" is a domain command. HOW the order is saved is up to the implementation of the service, which is only loosely coupled to the entity. This is a standard dependency injection technique. Of course you shouldn't put DB access code in entities. I'm failing to see how this is "against DDD core principles". Please be specific about what you mean.

Comment: @plalx : also, your comment regarding entities "know[ing] about the persistence details" is incorrect. In my example, the entity does NOT know the persistence details since it's only accessing the repository through an interface. The entity only knows the "what", not the "how"

Comment: Even if the entity delegates to a repository, the fact that it has a `save` method leaks persistence knowledge. The `save` operation means nothing to the business, it's not a business term or process, it's just a persistence concern. The domain model should only be expressed in business terms that forms the ubiquitous language. DDD is not only about OO done right, it's about reflecting the mind of business experts into code.

Comment: There is nothing wrong about dependency injection in general, but DDD entities are a very special kind of object that should have no construction dependencies except those required to respect initial invariants. What can be done however is to inject domain services at the method level, but the ISP should be followed in these rare cases. You can go read about it, there's a ton of articles on the subject of DDD entities and dependency injection and the most knowledgeable DDD practitionners such as Vaughn Vernon are advocating against constructor injection for entities.

Comment: In domain language, one says, "a user saves an order" and that is a valid business process. It doesn't "leak persistence knowledge" because the user doesn't know exactly what happens when the order is saved (nor do they care), and the business process of saving an order might involve other steps (data validation, etc.) than just dumping it to storage. I chose the name "Save" because OP asked about persistence ("save" is often used as a synonym for "persist"), but I could have named the method "Process" or "Submit" to imply other stuff the application service might do.

Comment: You're suggesting that "domain objects are passed to repositories", but if the entity itself shouldn't be responsible for that, then that business logic would have to be implemented in some other layer, resulting in a anemic entity. Again, "a user saves an order", not "a user sends an order to a repository, which then saves it". That's what happens under the covers, but a repository isn't something that exists in the ubiquitous domain language. Ask yourself if a user would know what a "repository" is.

Comment: Injecting loosely coupled services references into entities for concerns that lie outside the domain results in highly cohesive code, true to the DDD concept of entities having behavior.

Comment: I highly recommend that you read some DDD books. You are totally missing the point and the essence of DDD if you think `save` is a business operation. `"a user saves an order"` is not something that is expressed in domain concepts. `"A customer places an order"` could be however, but the fact that this could imply persisting the order using a persistence technology is totally irrelevant to the domain. Read Evans or Vernon, it will help you the understand DDD better, and not just the tactical patterns, but the strategic patterns which are as important if not more.